# Elastic search stats aggregation wrong result

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run a stats aggregation on the result of my match query with paginations.

```
POST catalog/product/_search
{
    "_source": ["price.new"],
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "type": "best_fields",
                  "query": "tie",
                  "fields": [
                     "name",
                     "name.search"
                  ],
                  "operator": "and",
                  "minimum_should_match": "30%"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from": 1,
   "size": 50,
   "sort": {
      "price.new": {
         "order": "asc"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "priceRange": {
         "stats": {
            "field": "price.new"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My minimum price product in the query result is : 8439

Where as the stats aggregation is showing : 7839

If I remove the size paramter from my query than the query return the product with price 7839.

Why there is this discrepancy if use `size` parameter.

I want my stats aggregation result to match with the current result set even if the result set is omitting some records the aggregation should reflect the query result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) in which you do a query and an aggregation, and you specify the size only in the query and not in the aggregation.

```
{"index" : "catalog", "size": 50 , "sort": {"price.new":{"order":"asc"   }}}
//your query
{"index" : "catalog"}
//your agggregation
```

Comment: Didn't get what you mean ?